# Fazer backspace quando pressiono tecla "+"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Numa dada `input` permito que o utilizador coloque o conteúdo que entender, mas ao pressionar a tecla `+` vai abrir uma `pop-up` (que está a funcionar) com dados vindos da base de dados. O que estou a tentar fazer agora é: Quando pressiono a tecla `+` abro a `pop-up`, e ao mesmo tempo dou um `backspace` na `input` para apagar este `+` pressionado na input.

*Input*:

```
<input type="text" id="inputIdCliente" class="form-control input-sm" onkeypress = "openSearchCliente(event)"/></td>
```

Função que abre a *pop-up*:

```
function openSearchCliente(e) {
        var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        if (unicode == 43) {
            popupSearchCliente.Show(); //Abre pop up
            //Código para dar backspace na input (em falta)
        }
    }
```

O que me falta mesmo é dar *backspace* na *input*, já procurei algumas coisas na net e não encontrei nenhuma solução que replicasse o que quero fazer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se é a maneira mais apropriada, mas acho que deve funcionar:

```
var t = $(this).val();
$(this).val(t.substr(0, t.length-1));
```

**#edit**

Como você está utilizando o event `keypress`, tente apenas com:

```
if (unicode == 43) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Seguindo o teu exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/Y9gVJ/

Comment: ele está a eliminar mal o carácter. Elimina o último inserido antes do `+` e não o `+`

Comment: Adicionei uma segunda opção, veja se funciona.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Não pensei que a solução passava pelo `preventDefault`... Obrigado :)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode testar as teclas que são pressionadas com `keyCode`, exemplo:

```
$('input[type=text]').keydown(function(e) {
        // se a tecla pressionada for "+"
        if (e.keyCode == 107) {
          //abre o pop-up
          alert('abre pop-up');
          //limpa o "+" digitado
          $(this).val($(this).val().replace("+", ""));

        }
    });
```

[Exemplo On-line](http://jsfiddle.net/nKduK/)

Se quiser remover somente o último caracter digitado:

```
$('input[type=text]').keydown(function(e) {
        // se a tecla pressionada for "+"
        if (e.keyCode == 107) {
          //abre o pop-up
          alert('abre pop-up');
          //limpa o "+" digitado
          $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).val().length-1));

        }
    });
```

[Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nKduK/2/)

Comment: E se o input já tiver algum valor com o caractere ```+```? No seu código ele seria removido junto.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com a solução para o caso citado.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta fazer um `return false;`

Exemplo:

```
function openSearchCliente(e) {
        var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        if (unicode == 43) {
            popupSearchCliente.Show(); //Abre pop up
            return false;
        }
    }
```